# A line code I wrote is marked as "unindent does not match any outer indentation level", why is this?

Tags: python, menu, definition

The block of code below is for context.

```
import requests
from termcolor import colored
import time
import replit
from time import sleep
import random
from random import seed
from random import randint
import sys

task1 = 0
task2 = 0
task3 = 0
task4 = 0
task5 = 0
task6 = 0
task7 = 0
task8 = 0
task9 = 0
task10 = 0
logout = 0

def mainterminal():
  print(colored("\n 1) Tasks \n 2) Device Management \n 3) Creature Information \n 4) Logoff", "white"))
  mtchoice = input()
  if mtchoice == "1":
   taskterminal()

def taskterminal():
  global task1
  global task2
  global task3
  global task4
  global task5
  global task6
  global task7
  global task8
  global task9
  global task10
  global logout
  print(colored("\n 1) Print Posters \n 2) Print Flyers \n 3) Wash Dishes \n 4) Clean Tables \n 5) Analyze Daily Revenue \n 6) Create New Playlist \n 7) Purchase Balloons \n 8) Purchase Paper Cups \n 9) Clean Stage \n 10) Refill Coffee \n 11) Return to main terminal", "white"))
  tchoice = input()
  if tchoice == "1":
   if task1 < 1:
    typer(colored("Printing Posters.", "blue"))
    print("")
    typer(colored("..........", "blue"))
    task1 = 0 + 1
    logout = 0 + 0.1 
    print(task1)
    print(logout)
    taskterminal()
  else:
   return(colored("Task is already completed", "red"))
   taskterminal()

 elif tchoice == "2":
   if task2 < 2:
    typer(colored("Printing Flyers.", "blue"))
    print("")
    typer(colored("..........", "blue"))
    task2 = 0 + 1
    logout = 0 + 0.1 
    print(task2)
    print(logout)
    taskterminal()
  else:
   return(colored("Task is already completed", "red"))
   taskterminal()
 elif tchoice == "11":
   replit.clear()
   mainterminal()


def typer(words):
  for char in words:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

def typertask(words):
  for char in words:
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

def typerslow(words):
  for char in words:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

This should work, but when I run it I get this error code

```
    elif tchoice == "2":
                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

The part which says **if tchoice == "1":** gives no error code, so I don't see why when you change it to **elif tchoice == "2":** it gives an error code.

Help?

I will give more parts of the code if you need it to help.

Comment: It is more about self debugging the code yourself. Python is very strict (in a cool way) about indentation. Check for spaces/tabs and try to be consistent. `elif tchoice == "2"` might be slightly off in terms of indentation

Comment: Usual practice is to add 4 spaces for indentation, that way is easier to track indentation problems. I suggest you start doing that so your code is easier to read both for you and potential colleagues. Also, pressing tab automatically adds 4 spaces so it won't be a chore, if that's your problem.

Comment: It's definitely off I can see that even from your snippet. But please, please, please, use 4 spaces!

Comment: And use a decent IDE that will help you to keep your indentation in check.

Comment: Maybe I should add, it is not just usual practice, it is required by PEP unless the project is PEP excempt. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: @Neil *"This document gives coding conventions for the Python code comprising the standard library in the main Python distribution."*  I'm going to go out on a limb and say that OP's code is not part of the standard library in the main Python distribution.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think the error message means? Do you understand what indentation is? It appears that you expect the `elif tchoice == "2":` line in question to correspond to the `if tchoice == "1":` one. Did you check how much each is indented? How much is each indented?

Answer (score 1):

Indentation was not proper in many parts of the code:

```
import requests
from termcolor import colored
import time
import replit
from time import sleep
import random
from random import seed
from random import randint
import sys

task1 = 0
task2 = 0
task3 = 0
task4 = 0
task5 = 0
task6 = 0
task7 = 0
task8 = 0
task9 = 0
task10 = 0
logout = 0

def mainterminal():
    print(colored("\n 1) Tasks \n 2) Device Management \n 3) Creature Information \n 4) Logoff", "white"))
    mtchoice = input()
    if mtchoice == "1":
        taskterminal()

def taskterminal():
    global task1
    global task2
    global task3
    global task4
    global task5
    global task6
    global task7
    global task8
    global task9
    global task10
    global logout
    print(colored("\n 1) Print Posters \n 2) Print Flyers \n 3) Wash Dishes \n 4) Clean Tables \n 5) Analyze Daily Revenue \n 6) Create New Playlist \n 7) Purchase Balloons \n 8) Purchase Paper Cups \n 9) Clean Stage \n 10) Refill Coffee \n 11) Return to main terminal", "white"))
    tchoice = input()
    if tchoice == "1":
        if task1 < 1:
            typer(colored("Printing Posters.", "blue"))
            print("")
            typer(colored("..........", "blue"))
            task1 = 0 + 1
            logout = 0 + 0.1 
            print(task1)
            print(logout)
            taskterminal()
        else:
            return(colored("Task is already completed", "red"))
            taskterminal()

    elif tchoice == "2":
        if task2 < 2:
            typer(colored("Printing Flyers.", "blue"))
            print("")
            typer(colored("..........", "blue"))
            task2 = 0 + 1
            logout = 0 + 0.1 
            print(task2)
            print(logout)
            taskterminal()
        else:
            return(colored("Task is already completed", "red"))
            taskterminal()

    elif tchoice == "11":
        replit.clear()
        mainterminal()


def typer(words):
    for char in words:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

def typertask(words):
    for char in words:
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

def typerslow(words):
    for char in words:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Try this and let me know if there's an issue. 
My advice for you would be to use a text editor or jupyter notebook which makes it easier to resolve the syntax related isssues.

Comment: i tried changing the code with the string you provided me, but now 

`seedvalue = input(typer(colored("Please input a random integer between 1 and 15 to start the booting terminal", "white")))
if seedvalue == "1" or seedvalue == "2" or seedvalue == "3" or seedvalue == "4" or seedvalue == "5" or seedvalue == "6" or seedvalue == "7" or seedvalue == "8" or seedvalue == "9" or seedvalue == "10" or seedvalue == "11" or seedvalue == "12" or seedvalue == "13" or seedvalue == "14" or seedvalue == "15":`

Is marked as invalid syntax?

Comment: You should attempt to write much less code at a time, and make sure the code you have written works before you attempt to add more features.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're providing the if condition in the very same line as your input. I'd recommend you to go through the syntaxes and indentations used in python for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The code has Indentation issue, I see you have mixed spaces in you if block, corrected it, working fine on my IDE (pyCharm), you can also use Sublime Text 3, its helpful tool to check you Indentation, You can also use View > Indentation > Intent Using Spaces.

```
import requests
from termcolor import colored
import time
import replit
from time import sleep
import random
from random import seed
from random import randint
import sys

task1 = 0
task2 = 0
task3 = 0
task4 = 0
task5 = 0
task6 = 0
task7 = 0
task8 = 0
task9 = 0
task10 = 0
logout = 0

def mainterminal():
  print(colored("\n 1) Tasks \n 2) Device Management \n 3) Creature Information \n 4) Logoff", "white"))
  mtchoice = input()
  if mtchoice == "1":
   taskterminal()

def taskterminal():
  global task1
  global task2
  global task3
  global task4
  global task5
  global task6
  global task7
  global task8
  global task9
  global task10
  global logout
  print(colored("\n 1) Print Posters \n 2) Print Flyers \n 3) Wash Dishes \n 4) Clean Tables \n 5) Analyze Daily Revenue \n 6) Create New Playlist \n 7) Purchase Balloons \n 8) Purchase Paper Cups \n 9) Clean Stage \n 10) Refill Coffee \n 11) Return to main terminal", "white"))
  tchoice = input()
  if tchoice == "1":
   if task1 < 1:
    typer(colored("Printing Posters.", "blue"))
    print("")
    typer(colored("..........", "blue"))
    task1 = 0 + 1
    logout = 0 + 0.1
    print(task1)
    print(logout)
    taskterminal()
   else:
    return colored("Task is already completed", "red")
    taskterminal()
  elif tchoice == "2":
   if task2 < 2:
    typer(colored("Printing Flyers.", "blue"))
    print("")
    typer(colored("..........", "blue"))
    task2 = 0 + 1
    logout = 0 + 0.1
    print(task2)
    print(logout)
    taskterminal()
   else:
    return(colored("Task is already completed", "red"))
    taskterminal()
  elif tchoice == "11":
   replit.clear()
   mainterminal()


def typer(words):
  for char in words:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

def typertask(words):
  for char in words:
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

def typerslow(words):
  for char in words:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```